# How can I add a value to an array that is a reference of another value in the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

For example, I want to set up something similar to this:

```js
var myArray = [
["Item 1", "pretext"+myArray[0][0]+"aftertext"],
["Item 1", "pretext"+myArray[1][0]+"aftertext"]
]
```

Any ideas how to do this? If possible at all?

Comment: You cannot reference an array from within itself. Also, in your example you try to use arr[0][0] in arr[0][1]? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. If you can form your question more concisely, I'll try to provide a better answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'm afraid your question is too vague to be usefully answered at present.

Answer (score 0):

Not how you do it. You need to have the previous element first EXIST in the array you are calling. You can't refer to a value that hasn't been set yet. You can do myArray[n+1]=some_fn(myArray[n]). You would use a for loop to accomplish this by creating and use Array push() method like myArray.push[new_element].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not in one line, because you **can't reference the array you are currently creating**.

```js
var items = ['item 1', 'item 1']
var myArray = []

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  myArray.push([items[i], 'pretext' + items[i] + 'aftertext'])
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do might be more easily accomplished by adjusting the order of array elements and using [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate prefixes and suffixes:

```js
var array = [
  ['pretext1 ', 'Item 1', ' aftertext1'],
  ['pretext2 ', 'Item 2', ' aftertext2']
]

console.log(array[0][1])
console.log(array[0].join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take the original, starting array and loop through it, modifying or adding the data for each array item.

So if my array is as follows:

```
var myArray = [
        ["item1", ""],
        ["item2", ""]
];
```

I could then do the following:

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, val){
     var newValue = 'some prefix-' + val[0] + '-some suffix';
     myArray[i][1]=newValue;
});
```

The resulting array would then contain the items:

```
["item1", "some prefix-item1-some suffix"],
["item2", "some prefix-item2-some suffix"]
```